# How to make this SQL query reasonably fast

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join, query-performance

I would like to optimize (read: make feasible at all) an SQL query.

The following PostgreSQL query retrieves the records I need. I (believe that I) could confirm that by running the query on a small subset of the actual DB.

```
SELECT B.*, A1.foo, A1.bar, A2.foo, A2.bar FROM B LEFT JOIN A as A1 on B.n1_id = A1.n_id LEFT JOIN A as A2 on B.n2_id = A2.n_id WHERE B.l_id IN (
    SELECT l_id FROM C 
        WHERE l_id IN (
            SELECT l_id FROM B 
                WHERE n1_id IN (SELECT n_id FROM A WHERE foo BETWEEN foo_min AND foo_max AND bar BETWEEN bar_min AND bar_max)
            UNION
            SELECT l_id FROM B 
                WHERE n2_id IN (SELECT n_id FROM A WHERE foo BETWEEN foo_min AND foo_max AND bar BETWEEN bar_min AND bar_max)
            ) 
            AND (property1 = 'Y' OR property2 = 'Y')
    )
```

The relevant part of the DB looks as follows:

```
table A:
n_id (PK);
foo, int (indexed);
bar, int (indexed);

table B:
l_id (PK);
n1_id (FK, indexed);
n2_id (FK, (indexed);

table C:
l_id (PK, FK);
property1, char (indexed);
property2, char (indexed);
```

`EXPLAIN` tells me this:

```
"Merge Join  (cost=6590667.27..10067376.97 rows=453419 width=136)"
"  Merge Cond: (A2.n_id = B.n2_id)"
"  ->  Index Scan using pk_A on A A2  (cost=0.57..3220265.29 rows=99883648 width=38)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=6590613.72..6591747.27 rows=453419 width=98)"
"        Sort Key: B.n2_id"
"        ->  Merge Join  (cost=3071304.25..6548013.91 rows=453419 width=98)"
"              Merge Cond: (A1.n_id = B.n1_id)"
"              ->  Index Scan using pk_A on A A1  (cost=0.57..3220265.29 rows=99883648 width=38)"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=3071250.74..3072384.28 rows=453419 width=60)"
"                    Sort Key: B.n1_id"
"                    ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=32475.31..3028650.92 rows=453419 width=60)"
"                          Hash Cond: (B.l_id = C.l_id)"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on B B  (cost=0.00..2575104.04 rows=122360504 width=60)"
"                          ->  Hash  (cost=26807.58..26807.58 rows=453419 width=16)"
"                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=10617.22..26807.58 rows=453419 width=16)"
"                                      ->  HashAggregate  (cost=10616.65..10635.46 rows=1881 width=8)"
"                                            ->  Append  (cost=4081.76..10611.95 rows=1881 width=8)"
"                                                  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=4081.76..5383.92 rows=1078 width=8)"
"                                                        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on A  (cost=4081.19..4304.85 rows=56 width=8)"
"                                                              Recheck Cond: ((bar >= bar_min) AND (bar <= bar_max) AND (foo >= foo_min) AND (foo <= foo_max))"
"                                                              ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=4081.19..4081.19 rows=56 width=0)"
"                                                                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on A_bar_idx  (cost=0.00..740.99 rows=35242 width=0)"
"                                                                          Index Cond: ((bar >= bar_min) AND (bar <= bar_max))"
"                                                                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on A_foo_idx  (cost=0.00..3339.93 rows=159136 width=0)"
"                                                                          Index Cond: ((foo >= foo_min) AND (foo <= foo_max))"
"                                                        ->  Index Scan using nx_B_n1 on B  (cost=0.57..19.08 rows=19 width=16)"
"                                                              Index Cond: (n1_id = A.n_id)"
"                                                  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=4081.76..5209.22 rows=803 width=8)"
"                                                        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on A A_1  (cost=4081.19..4304.85 rows=56 width=8)"
"                                                              Recheck Cond: ((bar >= bar_min) AND (bar <= bar_max) AND (foo >= foo_min) AND (foo <= foo_max))"
"                                                              ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=4081.19..4081.19 rows=56 width=0)"
"                                                                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on A_bar_idx  (cost=0.00..740.99 rows=35242 width=0)"
"                                                                          Index Cond: ((bar >= bar_min) AND (bar <= bar_max))"
"                                                                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on A_foo_idx  (cost=0.00..3339.93 rows=159136 width=0)"
"                                                                          Index Cond: ((foo >= foo_min) AND (foo <= foo_max))"
"                                                        ->  Index Scan using nx_B_n2 on B B_1  (cost=0.57..16.01 rows=14 width=16)"
"                                                              Index Cond: (n2_id = A_1.n_id)"
"                                      ->  Index Scan using pk_C on C  (cost=0.57..8.58 rows=1 width=8)"
"                                            Index Cond: (l_id = B.l_id)"
"                                            Filter: ((property1 = 'Y'::bpchar) OR (property2 = 'Y'::bpchar))"
```

All three tables have millions of rows. I cannot change the table definitions.
The `WHERE l_id IN ( SELECT l_id FROM B...UNION...)` is very restrictive and returns < 100 results.

What can I do to make the query execute in a reasonable amount of time (a few seconds max)?

**EDIT**: forgot to select two columns in the outermost `SELECT`. That should now change this question though.

**UPDATE**
This seems to be a difficult question, possibly due to lack of information on my part. I would love to give more information, however the data base is properietary and confidential.

I can retrieve the rows of B with all conditions reasonably fast (0.1 s) with the following query:

```
WITH relevant_a AS (
    SELECT * FROM A 
        WHERE
            foo BETWEEN foo_min AND foo_max 
            AND
            bar BETWEEN bar_min AND bar_max
)
WITH relevant_c AS (
    SELECT * FROM C
        WHERE l_id IN (
            SELECT l_id FROM B
                WHERE n1_id IN (
                    SELECT n_id FROM relevant_a
                )
            UNION
            SELECT l_id FROM B
                WHERE n2_id IN (
                    SELECT n_id FROM relevant_a
                )
        )
        AND
        (property1 = 'Y' OR property2= 'Y')
),
relevant_b AS (
    SELECT * FROM B WHERE l_id IN (
        SELECT l_id FROM relevant_c
    )
)

SELECT * FROM relevant_b
```

The join with A is the part where it becomes slow. The query returns < 100 records, so why does the join with A make it so slow?. Do you have any ideas how to make this simple join faster? It should not be that costly to simply add four columns of information from another table.

Comment: I imagine the key here is going to be re-working those sub-queries to be conditional joins, since that will give the query planner much more freedom to optimise things.

Comment: `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` would tell us more. You might want to post it to http://explain.depesz.com/ and add the link to your question. Also, your *actual* table definitions with exact data types and all constraints would help - what you get with `\d tbl` in `psql`.

Comment: Can you alias all the columns in your query with appropriate table aliases?  It isn't obvious what the query is doing.

Comment: to Start with change the INs to Exists

Comment: `A.n_id` should be `A2.n_id` I assume?

Comment: Can B.n1_id and B.n2_id be NULL?

Comment: Can you tell us the cardinality of each table?

Comment: May be try changing the UNION to UNION ALL. It should get rid of a sort operation.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, I will try out your suggestions on monday.

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter You are right. The anonymization of the actual tables was error prone. I already corrected the mistake.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner none of the used columns can be null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could make it work with the following query:

```
WITH relevant_a AS (
    SELECT * FROM A 
        WHERE
            foo BETWEEN foo_min AND foo_max 
            AND
            bar BETWEEN bar_min AND bar_max
),
relevant_c AS (
    SELECT * FROM C
        WHERE l_id IN (
            SELECT l_id FROM B
                WHERE n1_id IN (
                    SELECT n_id FROM relevant_a
                )
            UNION
            SELECT l_id FROM B
                WHERE n2_id IN (
                    SELECT n_id FROM relevant_a
                )
        )
        AND
        (property1 = 'Y' OR property2= 'Y')
),
relevant_b AS (
    SELECT * FROM B WHERE l_id IN (
        SELECT l_id FROM relevant_c
    )
),
a1_data AS (
    SELECT A.n_id, A.foo, A.bar
    FROM A
    WHERE A.n_id IN (
        SELECT n1_id FROM relevant_b
    )
)
a2_data AS (
    SELECT A.n_id, A.foo, A.bar
    FROM A
    WHERE A.n_id IN (
        SELECT n2_id FROM relevant_b
    )
)

SELECT relevant_b.*, a1_data.foo,  a1_data.bar,  a2_data.foo,  a2_data.bar 
FROM relevant_b
LEFT JOIN a1_data ON relevant_b.n1_id = a1_data.n_id
LEFT JOIN a2_data ON relevant_b.n2_id = a2_data.n_id
```

I do not like this solution as it seems forced and redundant. However, it gets the job done in < 0.1 s.

I still refuse to believe that an SQL noob like me can (quite easily in retrospect) come up with a statement that forces the optimizer to use a strategy much better than the one it comes up with on its own. There has to be a better solution but I will not be looking for one anymore.

Regardless, thank you all for your suggestions, I definetely learned a few things on the way.

Answer (score 2):

Or something like this:

```
SELECT B.*, A1.foo, A2.bar 
FROM B 
     LEFT JOIN A as A1 on B.n1_id = A1.n_id 
     LEFT JOIN A as A2 on B.n2_id = A2.n_id 
     INNER JOIN C on (C.l_id = B.l_id)
where 
     A1.foo between A1.foo_min AND A1.foo_max AND 
     A2.bar BETWEEN A2.bar_min AND A2.bar_max and
     b.foo between b.foo_min AND b.foo_max AND 
     b.bar BETWEEN b.bar_min AND bar_max   AND
     (C.property1 = 'Y' OR C.property2 = 'Y')
```

Comment: The reference to `a` is invalid. You would have to rewrite the query to fix.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, I will try out your suggestions on monday.

Comment: I am sorry, but that did not work. The lines beginning with b.foo and b.bar are not valid (and not needed) since table B does not have such fields. Between the first and second WHERE line there should be an OR instead of an AND. But even with those corrections the query is too slow (cancelled after 10 seconds). EXPLAIN shows that the optimizer is performing a right join with cost of over 9 million and then sort with again 9 million.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could club both the `Left joins` on **A (A1,A2)** into 1 `Left join` and use a `OR` for the `ON` Clause
2. Change `INs` to `Exists`
3. Change the `UNION` into 1 query using a `OR` Clause

Try this...

```
    SELECT B.*
    , A1.foo
    , A2.bar
FROM B
LEFT JOIN A AS A1
    ON (
            B.n1_id = A1.n_id
            OR B.n2_id = A1.n_id
            )
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT l_id
        FROM C
        WHERE EXISTS (
                SELECT l_id
                FROM B
                WHERE EXISTS (
                        SELECT n_id
                        FROM A
                        WHERE foo BETWEEN foo_min
                                AND foo_max
                            AND bar BETWEEN bar_min
                                AND bar_max
                            AND (
                                A.n_id = B.n_id
                                OR A.n_id = B.n2_id
                                )
                        )
                    AND B.l_id = C.l_id
                )
        )
```

Comment: This approach is missing the property1 and property2 clauses. Also the distinction between A! and A2, which I need, is gone. I still executed the query (with the added property clauses), but had to cancel it after 10 seconds. EXPLAIN shows a nested loop left join with a cost of 2 trillion.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see it, you select B where at least one of the two associated As is within the given ranges. Moreover you require there exists a C for the B. Then you show foo and bar of the two associated As with the B values.

```
SELECT B.*, A1.foo, A2.bar
FROM B 
LEFT JOIN A A1 ON A1.n_id = B.n1_id
LEFT JOIN A A2 ON A2.n_id = B.n2_id
WHERE 
(
  (A1.foo BETWEEN foo_min AND foo_max AND A1.bar BETWEEN bar_min AND bar_max)
  OR
  (A2.foo BETWEEN foo_min AND foo_max AND A2.bar BETWEEN bar_min AND bar_max)
)
AND EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM C
  WHERE C.l_id = B.l_id
  AND (property1 = 'Y' OR property2 = 'Y')
);
```

Can B.n1_id and B.n2_id be NULL? Then you need the left outer joins. Otherwise you can replace them with inner joins.

EDIT: Oops I missed the C criteria. I've altered the statement accordingly.

EDIT: Reacting to your comments, here is the same select with INNER JOINs and an IN clause:

```
SELECT B.*, A1.foo, A2.bar
FROM B 
INNER JOIN A A1 ON A1.n_id = B.n1_id
INNER JOIN A A2 ON A2.n_id = B.n2_id
WHERE 
(
  (A1.foo BETWEEN foo_min AND foo_max AND A1.bar BETWEEN bar_min AND bar_max)
  OR
  (A2.foo BETWEEN foo_min AND foo_max AND A2.bar BETWEEN bar_min AND bar_max)
)
AND B.l_id IN
(
  SELECT l_id
  FROM C
  WHERE property1 = 'Y' OR property2 = 'Y'
);
```

Comment: In the EXPLAIN to this query there is no nested loop, which is further than I had gotten. I still had to cancel the query after 10 seconds. I see a "merge right join' with cost of 12 million at the first line.

Comment: Well, some queries take time ;-) How many records are in B? How strong does the EXISTS clause reduce this? Do I get, say, 50% of B or rather 0.5% of B with the exists clause? Again: Can B.n1_id and B.n2_id be NULL? A merge join doesn't sound to bad. At least for many data. First sorting, then matching. AFAIK, postgresql doesn't have a hash join technique like Oracle, so the merge method seems the best you can get.

Comment: Ah, I just notice: In the comments to your request you say neither B.n1_id nor B.n2_id can be NULL. Then replace the LEFT JOINs with INNER JOINs. Maybe that makes a difference. (But actually the dbms should notice things like that and turn the outer joins into inner joins itself.)

Comment: I am sorry, I did not see your comment prior to answering my own question. I found a query that takes < 0.1 s, so this is none of the queries that take time :-). As hinted at in the question A and B have ~100 million records, C has ~70 million. Every C is a B. About 1 % of C fulfills the property clause.

Comment: So you would like to force the check on C to be first. Maybe you can achieve this by replacing the EXISTS clause with an IN clause. The dbms may then decide to get that list first. Then the joins would have to take place on only 1% of the B records. And as mentioned, use INNER JOINs. I'll update my answer, so you can try it.

Comment: I tried your updated solution, but it still takes too long. The most restrictive clauses in the whole query are the two BETWEENs. They reduce the ~100 million records in B to < 100. While I appreciate your persistency I do not want to spend any more time on this, now that I have a working query. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

There should be only one index for both columns foo and bar in Table A, so this would be optimal for both between clauses (find by your self witch would be the better columns order)
Table B is not optimally designed for this query, you should traspose values n1_id and n2_id in 2 different rows with same key and column_id (crosstab).

The follwing query should return then same data with a huge perfomance improvement.

```
with b_norm(l_id, role, n_id) as (
        select l_id, unnest(Array['1','2']) as role, unnest(Array[n1_id, n2_id]) as n_id
        from b
    )
select *
from (
        select distinct l_id
        from a
            join b_norm using (n_id)
            join c using (l_id)
        where bar between 0 and 10000
            and foo between 10000 and 20000
            and (c.property1 = 'Y' or c.property2 = 'Y')
    ) as driver
    join b using (l_id)
    join (
        select a.n_id as n1_id, foo as foo1, bar as bar1
        from a
    )  as a1 using (n1_id)
    join (
        select a.n_id as n2_id, foo as foo2, bar as bar2
        from a
    ) as a2 using (n2_id);
```